# How to optimize a very simple Python tkinter particle "physics engine"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, physics, particle-system

My hope is to create a simple but well optimized particle system from scratch using python 3.x, Numpy and Tkinter to display it that allows for the simulation of the maximum number of identical particles.

My code.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import random as rm

class particle:
    def __init__(self, p, v, a=np.array([0,10]), colour="blue"):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(p[0]-2, p[1]-2, p[0]+2, p[1]+2, fill = colour) 
        self.p = np.array([float(i) for i in p]) #position
        self.v =np.array([float(i) for i in v]) #velocity
        self.oldv = np.copy(v)
        self.a = np.array([float(i) for i in a]) # accelleration
        self.colour = colour

    def update(self, delay):
        self.v += self.a*delay
        self.p += (self.v*delay)
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.v[0]*delay, self.v[1]*delay)

        if not 0<self.p[0]<800: #keeps it within boundaries
            self.v *= np.array([-1,1])
        if not 0<self.p[1]<400:
            self.v *= np.array([1,-1])

    def collide(self, other):
        x = self.p-other.p
        mag = np.sqrt(x.dot(x)) # checks distance
        if 0<mag<4:
            self.oldv = np.copy(self.v)
            x /= mag

            inline = x*x.dot(self.v)
            inlineo = x*x.dot(other.oldv)

            self.v -= inline - inlineo

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    [i.update(Time_per_frame) for i in particles]

    [[j.collide(i) for i in particles] for j in particles]

    canvas.after(int(Time_per_frame*1000),main)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#creates the window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ball Bouncer")
root.resizable(False,False)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.config(bg="white")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#set variables
Time_per_frame = 0.02
NoParticles = 100
particles = [particle([rm.randint(100,700),rm.randint(100,300)], [rm.randint(-100,100),rm.randint(-100,100)],[0,0]) for i in range(100)]
#particles = [particle([50,53],[50,0],[0,0]),particle([150,50],[-50,0],[0,0])]

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

main()

root.mainloop()
```

My code as is is able to run smoothly with about 100 particles which is less than I expected. Is there anything obvious that is slowing my code down.

My coding experience is very limited and primarily self taught so please inform me of any coding faux pas I have committed. This code is a primarily a learning exercise for myself as I understand that their is existing tools.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A lot of optimisation can come from you checking not collision between every particle but instead only the particles near by, try looking into quadtree

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look into it.

Comment: There is also small things like always recreating the vectors n the collision instead of storing them once.

Comment: You should also leverage numpy much more. Instead of using particle objects, use numpy arrays with coordinates. Then perform computations within numpy (this fast) on all of them ‚at once‘. Obviously that’s not really true, but within one numpy call, the speed is manifold.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying @deets. My positions are all numpy arrays. Sorry If i'm overlooking something.

Comment: "optimize" and "very simple" don't mix well... Have you profiled your program to measure where the time is spent? It is probably in the collide double loop that @Alessi42 mentioned, but best to verify.

Comment: I meant simple as in the functionality for example all particles are equal size and mass meaning momentum calculation isn't necessary. However your point is correct. I am going to add some time functionality to check delay location as suggested.

Comment: @HReed your positions are numpy arrays, but only one coordinate *per object*. What I'm talking about is having a numpy array of shape (2, <number-of-particles>) that holds *ALL* coordinates for the particles. And then testing `bouncing = coords[:,0] > 800` gives you *ALL* particle indices that violate the bounding box condition. Then `speeds[bouncing] * flip_x` bounces them. And so on.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.